# Cant paste flipped pose properly

Tags: pose-mode, dopesheet

I cant properly flip the pose in dope sheet. I created the 1st half of the walking sequence, now im trying to flip it using shift+ctrl+c(in gif). The problem is it doesnt even paste everything. I tried duplicating it then mirroring it(in gif), i tried to flip it on the x axis.

[[image: 1]]

[image]

Comment: hello, you need to check the bones name and their orientation, but maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I added the project. The bone names and orientation are right in my opinion. I hope you can help me :D

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3L64r5zQ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3L64r5zQ/)

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't paste everything"? It seems to work fine actually...

Comment: if you look at the first part of the GIF youll see that i selected everything, copied it, then ctrl+shift+v, but it only pasted the hips, torso, chest and neck keyframes

Comment: Yes. It works now. I read somewhere that the L/R/Left/Right can be wherever as long as they have a dot or a space between words, so i just typed it as it felt natural to type (ex:left foot, left finger)

Comment: Ok I've never heard it was possible to use prefixes, but it looks like they haven't implemented them everywhere  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've called your bones *Left_Shoulder* and *Right_Shoulder* (prefixes), and so on for the other bones, instead of *Shoulder_L* and *Shoulder_R* (suffixes). Actually I was a bit surprised that you were able to copy flip with this kind of terminology. That said, it looks like in the *Dopesheet*, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> you still need to use suffixes. I guess it's something they have forgotten to fix: Either you can use prefixes everywhere or you can't, or I miss something...

Answer (score -1):

I added the project. The bone names and orientation are right in my opinion. I hope you can help me :D

[image]

Comment: please don't use the Your Answer field, it's only for people to give answer, instead use the "add a comment" function

Comment: ... and copy link to your blend into your Qeustion via "Edit", Thank you

Comment: yea... i missclicked

Comment: Thank you :) Do you have a privilage to delete this Answer? Please do it. Thank you

Comment: i dont really know how. it is the first time using this site, and i cant see a "delete answer" button